# Как можно выделить все оттенки красного цвета из картинки?

Tags: python, изображения, opencv, обработка-изображений

У меня есть изображение, которое состоит из 3х цветов и их оттенков (красный, синий, черный). Пикселей различных оттенков >35к. Я пробовал применить алгоритм кластеризации для разбиения картинки по 3-м цветам, но результат оказался довольно не точным, так как к черному цвету алгоритм относил нужные мне пиксели красного оттенка и некоторые пиксели синего. Хотел прописать строгое условие принадлежности красному цвету, но никак не могу выделить строгие границы для каждого из каналов. Подскажите, в каком диапазоне лежит красный цвет и как прописать для него строгие границы?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42882724/7485582

Comment: Ну, такое. Границы цветов довольно размыты. Можно проверять, например, чтобы красной компоненты было больше, чем синей и зелёной, но вопрос - насколько больше её должно быть, чтобы это было различимо.